# Bézout's Identity vs. Fermat's Little Theorem for Finding Modular Multiplicative Inverses

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

While studying how to calculate the multiplicative inverse $a^{-1}$ of a number $a$ such that $a\cdot a^{-1} \equiv 1\mod p$, I found the majority of online resources  immediately point to Bézout's identity for a solution. Nevertheless, I find the inverse is way easier to obtain through Fermat's little theorem: $a^{-1} = a^{p-2}\mod p$

Is there an advantage to using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm (Bézout) over Fermat's Little Theorem? Am I missing something?

I wonder whether Bézout's identity provides a more generalized solution, or whether modular exponentiation (FLT) is more computationally costly than EEA.

Comment: Bezout also works for $a\cdot b\equiv 1 \bmod m$, where $m$ is not prime.

Comment: There is  a *fast exponentiation* algorithm, but it all depends on the size of the involved numbers.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, when $m$ is not prime, the equivalent of Fermat's theorem is Euler's theorem but of course the point is that computing $\phi(m)$ is not easy if you can't factor $m$.

Comment: @lhs Yes, I know. I can understand that one would like to stay with Fermat's little theorem (the OP says it is "way easier" - than EEA?). Of course, the question also might only refer to "computationally costly". Then my remark is irrelevant.

Comment: (Extended) Euclid is very very fast even for huge numbers. Exponentiation not so much.